# How to return from sourcing function in sourced code?

Tags: bash, function, include

Consider foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo() {
   source another.sh
   echo "This shouldn't be executed. Return code: $?"
   return 0
}

foo
echo "Return code: $?"
```

Then another.sh:

```
echo "Inside another.sh"
return 1
```

Running `./foo.sh` prints:

```
Inside another.sh
This shouldn't be executed. Return code: 1
Return code: 0
```

Is there an alternative method to include a source file into another such that the `return` command would return from the function enclosing include command rather than from the command itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to *propagate the return code* in foo.sh:

```
source another.sh || return $?
```

Then:

```
$ ./foo.sh
Inside another.sh
Return code: 1
```

Alternatively, *exit from the whole script* in another.sh:

```
exit 1
```

Then:

```
$ ./foo.sh
Inside another.sh
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Just came to the same solution independently. However that wouldn't work if `another.sh` would return 0 :)

Comment: Exiting from this script won't do either as I need to continue running the script after calling foo. This is just a small example.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov: You might want to post *what* you're trying to do rather than *how*. Often solutions like this one (not very elegant) can be avoided by taking a different approach.

Comment: I am just breaking a large function into several source files, so that they are easier to manage. But I still want to be able to return from it.

Comment: If you mean that you want to break out of the script if it fails, a better solution might be `set -o errexit`. With `nounset`, `pipefail` and `noclobber`, this is one of the most useful safety nets I've ever used in Bash scripts.

Comment: Actually I am writing a build script for one project in a generic build system. The proper way to return errors back to the system is to return non-zero value from the build function. In other words I don't want to screw other projects if mine will fail :)

Comment: Since there is no better answer I'll mark this as an answer as it offers a solution to my problem.